# Big Theta asymptotic analysis

Tags: runtime, analysis, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

Given that f(n) ∈ Ѳ(g(n)); how can you prove that 2^(f(n)) ∈ Ѳ(2^(g(n)))?
I have tried using limits of big theta and using first principles, no luck. Please help

Comment: You should show what you did. Otherwise is seems that you simply forward your work to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hint, this statement is false. Try taking two functions that are constant multiples of one another.

Hope this helps!